# JAX-WS client creation

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, webservice-client, webservices-client

I am newbie to JAX-WS. I want to create a client for a webservice interface, so that i can test the webservice interface.

Please share link/resource or any approaches for JAX-WS client creation if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example : [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/). There is a complete example of server/client implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy, You can start with `wsimport` to create client from JAX-WS wsdl file. `wsimport` can be found in `JAVA_HOME/bin`. Or you can use SOAP-UI application to generate `jax-ws artifacts`